# How to fix 'not assignable' error in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I wrote an simple class, the error just makes non-sense.

```js
class C {
  static find<T extends typeof C>(
    this: T,
    selector?: { [P in keyof InstanceType<T>]?: (InstanceType<T>)[P] },
  ) {
    // error: Type '{ id: 1; }' is not assignable
    /// to type '{ [P in keyof InstanceType<T>]?: InstanceType<T>[P]; }'.ts(2322)
    if (!selector) selector = { id: 1 };

    return Collection.find(selector);
  }

  id: number;
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: relevant: [Microsoft/TypeScript#13442](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13442) and [others](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17071).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem** is that there might be constraint in the child `T` that is not in the parent `C`. What you're facing is similar to this scenario in which the child has a narrower type than the parent has:

```
type Parent = { id: number; }

type Child = { id: 10 }

type ExtendsParent<T extends Parent> = T;

const p: Parent = { id: 1 };

// Type 'Parent' is not assignable to type 'Child'.
// Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type '10'.
const c: ExtendsParent<Child> = p;
```

Since the `Child` type could be narrower than the `Parent` is, we can safely assign a `Child` to a `Parent`, but we cannot assign a `Parent` to a `Child`.

In your scenario, a **possible solution** - if you think you know better than the compiler - is to use a type assertion like this:

```
selector = { id: 1 } as typeof selector;
```

Here is all of the above [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20P%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20find%3CC%20extends%20P%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this%3A%20C%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20selector%3F%3A%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20C%5D%3F%3A%20C%5BP%5D%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20selector%20%3D%20%7B%20id%3A%201%20%7D%20as%20typeof%20selector%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Parent%20%3D%20%7B%20id%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Child%20%3D%20%7B%20id%3A%2010%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ExtendsParent%3CT%20extends%20Parent%3E%20%3D%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20p%3A%20Parent%20%3D%20%7B%20id%3A%201%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Type%20'Parent'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'Child'.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Types%20of%20property%20'id'%20are%20incompatible.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Type%20'number'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'10'.%0D%0Aconst%20c%3A%20ExtendsParent%3CChild%3E%20%3D%20p%3B) (without all the extra `InstanceType` stuff).

Comment: It's `Partial` though, so that would be okay. The real problem would be if `T`'s instance type had a numeric literal of (say) `2` for `id`, so `T extends typeof C` would be true but `{id: 1}` would not be assignable to an instance of it.

Comment: It sounds like a bug?

Comment: I wouldn't consider it a bug, because the child type could be narrower than the parent type is, and assigning the parent type to the child type could lose type information. If the child type says, *My id is always 10*, and the parent type says, *My id can be any number*, then assigning a parent to a child is incorrect. Imagine a situation when the parent has a property of type of `object` and the child has the same property of type `string`. In that case, it's more clear that assigning a parent to a child is incorrect, because an `object` is not a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be an option:

```
class C {
    static find<T extends typeof C>(
        this: T,
        selector?: { [P in keyof InstanceType<T>]?: (InstanceType<T>)[P] } | C,
    ) {
        if (!selector) {
            selector = { id: 1 };
        }

        return Collection.find(selector);
    }

    id: number;
}
```